# Trying to implement a priority queue with an ordered linked list

Tags: java, linked-list, queue, priority-queue

So what I'm trying to do is implement a priority queue using an ordered linked list. I feel like I am fairly close but I can't seem to resolve the error in the while statement within the insert function. Here's what I have so far:

```
class OrderedLinkedListMaxPQ<Item> {

private class PQNode {
    Object data; 
    PQNode next;

    public PQNode(Object value) {
        data = value;
        next = null;
    }
}

PQNode head;

public void PriorityQueue() { 
    this.head = null; 
}

public boolean isEmpty() { return this.head == null; }

public void insert(Object item) {

   PQNode prev = null;
   PQNode current = this.head;
   while (current != null && current.data >= item.data) {
       prev = current;
       current = current.next;
   }

   PQNode temp = new PQNode(item);
   if (prev == null) {
       temp.next = this.head;
       this.head = temp;
   } else {
       temp.next = current;
       prev.next = temp;
   }   
}

public Object delete() {
   Object temp = this.head.data;
   this.head = this.head.next;
   return temp;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    OrderedLinkedListMaxPQ<Integer> pq = new OrderedLinkedListMaxPQ<Integer>();
    pq.insert(7);
    pq.insert(6);
    pq.insert(3);
    pq.insert(2);
    while (!pq.isEmpty())
        StdOut.println(pq.delete());
   }
}
```

Comment: on the first insert(), don't you get a NullPointer?

Comment: @iluxa If you mean because of the while condition, it should short circuit and not hit current.data.

Comment: "Implement a priority queue using an ordered linked list." Why? Something wrong with `java.util.PriorityQueue`? It's *O(log(N)).* Yours is *O(N).* Don't do this.

Answer (score 1):

`current.data >= item.data` makes no sense. The `data` is an Object reference and you cannot compare them. Perhaps, if the dat avalues are `Comparable` you can use the [compareTo(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) method. Otherwise you will need to write your own mechanism to compare them. Also, `item` is passed in as an Object, but you references it as a `PNode` ... this is a problem too.

Comment: Thanks for your help. How would I go about implementing compareTo into this class? Should I make a separate helper method that compares the two values? Sorry, I'm just a bit lost on this.